# How i can use unison to sync. file of folders with the latest modification time?

Tags: unix, asynchronous, synchronization, aix, unison

How i can use `unison` to sync folders with the latest modification time of its file

Example :-
folder_1/file.txt changed at 12:30
folder_2/file.txt changed at 12:35

i wanna execute `./unison` to give me the following result :-
update file with regards to latest modification time so that update file `folder_1/file.txt` to became the same file `folder_2.file.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Unison works by comparing both files with their last synchronized version. If both have changed, and the end result is not identical, they are marked as a conflict. Although in that case a merge program can be invoked to resolve the conflict, the modification time plays no role at all in the whole process.

From the manual:

> Note that whether a path is updated has nothing to do with its last
>   modification time—Unison considers only the contents when determining
>   whether an update has occurred. This means that touching a file
>   without changing its contents will not be recognized as an update. A
>   file can even be changed several times and then changed back to its
>   original contents; as long as Unison is only run at the end of this
>   process, no update will be recognized.

Comment: What about with the `merge` option for *.txt files?  I'm looking for a method to always favor the _older_ for *.last files